# MySQL update table dynamically

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I wonder if there is a way to have an SQL table update itself dynamically.
I have table1 and table2 and I need to create a table3 using UNION and WHERE both tables ID column (PK) match but the issue is that I do not want to always create the same table3 instead if I add a record to the tables , let it appear automatically appear in table 3..

Any advise how it is done if possible or where should I look into?

Thanks

Comment: and the Downvote ?  :/

Comment: Wasn't me.  But don't take votes personally, they're anonymous by design.

Comment: @Awena . . . Or just delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Table3` shouldn't be a table, it should be a [view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html).

From the perspective of any given `SELECT` query and any consuming application looking at the data, a view can be treated like any other table.  The fact that it's not a table is entirely transparent in those cases.

What a view does is compile and store a query which examines other tables, and presents the results of that query in a table structure.  So any time you select from the view, you're dynamically selecting from the current state of the tables it examines.